# Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to model.company

Tags: c#, linq, castle-activerecord

I am trying to make an anonymous object to fetch the data and pass it to view for display. To avoid parsing the data on view level I am trying to get all the information in that anonymous object. Here is my code:

```
var list = new DataBaseRepository<CrashPlan>().FindAll(x => x.Company.State == "active").Select
                (crashObject => new
                {
                    Company = crashObject.Company,
                    Users = crashObject.Users.Count
                });

            PropertyBag["items"] = list.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Company.CompanyName);
```

But when I execute this code I get this error:

```
Inner exception:
InvalidCastException

Message:
Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'Dicom.Dinet.Core.Models.Company'.
```

And I have no idea what to fix in the code so that error can be fix.

Comment: As an aside, why do you do: `list.ToList().OrderBy(...)`? You are creating an in-memory list before you start ordering, that makes the list redundant. Use `ToList` at the end if you want a list.

Comment: is `crashObject.Company` an `int`?

Comment: Please post both `CrashPlan` and `Company`.

Comment: @Default crashObject.Company is an object that points to Company model.

Comment: @Default but **crashObject.Users.Count** is an integer value.

Comment: is the exception thrown in the `ToList` call or the `OrderBy` call? If you store the result in a temporary variable it might be easier to debug.

Comment: @Default after saving the result in temp variable it throws exception on **ToList()**. Also when I remove **crashObject.USers.count** from it. It works.

Comment: What is `PropertyBag["items"]`? And if you do this `var whatIsThisData = list.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Company.CompanyName);` then it works? And if it works then match data types of `whatisThisData` and `PropertyBag["items"]`.